# How to convert an URL absolute path to relative path

Tags: c#, asp.net, relative-path, absolute-path

For example, I have:

```
string AbsImgURL = "~/MyStuff/Images/MsgBoxIcon/MyImg.jpg";
```

I want it to be:

```
string AbsImgURL = "../../MyStuff/Images/MsgBoxIcon/MyImg.jpg"
```

(Because I am currently at the page "~/UI/Pages/Default.aspx", which is two level deep from the root)

Comment: What's wrong with [VirtualPathUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Brad: First time I heard of it, would you please show me how?

Comment: Have you tried `VirtualPathUtility.MakeReleative`

Comment: Ben: Please show me an example of how to use it.

Comment: I could write you an algorithm for it, but Ben's way is much easier.

Comment: Please give me an example of how to use VirtualPathUtility.MakeRelative

Comment: You just do `VirtualPathUtility.MakeRelative("~/FromPath/","~/ToPath/")` this should return `../ToPath/`

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.makerelative(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have out it working. Thanks Guys. See my code below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guy, I have finally get it worked by using VirtualPathUtility.MakeRelative. The code is below:

```
     /// <summary>Convert and URL Absoluate Path to Relative Path 
     ///(For Example: "~/MyStuff/Images/MsgBoxIcon/MyImg.jpg" ==> "../../MyStuff/Images/MsgBoxIcon/MyImg.jpg"
     ///(Assuming client is currently at the page "~/UI/Pages/Default.aspx", which is two level deep from the root).</summary>
    private static string ConvertAbsoluteToRelativePath(string Input)
    {
        //Init
        string Output = "";

        //Get Current URL (Ex: http://MyWebSite//...)
        string CurrentURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

        //Convert to Relative Path
        Output = VirtualPathUtility.MakeRelative(CurrentURL, Input);

        //Finally
        return Output;
    }
```